# ELK Stack - Remote servers' logs parsed and classed correctly, but dumped to stout not elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

As the (lengthy) topic suggests, my remote servers sends logs to the logstash server.

Here the logstash configs:

Input:

```
[root@tool01 conf.d]# cat 01-lumberjack-input.conf
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
```

Type:

```
[root@tool01 conf.d]# cat 10-syslog.conf
    filter {
      if [type] == "syslog" {
        grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname}     %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
          add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
          add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
        }
        syslog_pri { }
        date {
          match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Output:

```
[root@tool01 conf.d]# cat 30-lumberjack-output.conf
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The local logs are working fine as metioned, but all the logs from remote is sent to stdout:

```
[root@tool01 logstash]# tail -n 19 logstash.stdout
{
             "message" => "Nov 29 20:16:44 foreman dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.50.100 to 3c:4a:92:12:1c:cb via eth0",
            "@version" => "1",
          "@timestamp" => "2014-11-29T20:16:44.000Z",
                "type" => "syslog",
                "file" => "/var/log/messages",
                "host" => "foreman.ics.dmz",
              "offset" => "3511785",
    "syslog_timestamp" => "Nov 29 20:16:44",
     "syslog_hostname" => "foreman",
      "syslog_program" => "dhcpd",
      "syslog_message" => "DHCPACK on 192.168.50.100 to 3c:4a:92:12:1c:cb via eth0",
         "received_at" => "2014-11-29 07:16:46 UTC",
       "received_from" => "foreman.ics.dmz",
"syslog_severity_code" => 5,
"syslog_facility_code" => 1,
     "syslog_facility" => "user-level",
     "syslog_severity" => "notice"
}
```

This may be a stupid question, but I only have the shipper installed on the client server, do I need to have logstash running there as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your output{} stanza will try to send to elasticsearch on the local machine and also print to stdout.  That part looks fine.  Is elasticsearch running on the local machine?  Can you locally telnet to the port (9300, I believe)?

Comment: Yup, elasticsearch is listening on 9200 and 9300.
:::9300 & :::9200
Inserts there should happen from the local instance of logstash, so I presume the fact that it is on a ipv6 address should not matter since local logs are fed fine correct?

Comment: Mmm.. Ok, slight confusion now. I did not change anything, after posting my question I went to bed. This morning I have data from the other machines...
Why would there be such a huge delay in them appearing in the stout log to when they are available in Kibana? The delay is more than an hour?
Could it be due to this:  (/etc/sysconfig/logstash-forwarder)
LOGSTASH_FORWARDER_OPTIONS="-config /etc/logstash-forwarder -spool-size 100"

Comment: Ok, so it is still not working correctly for all machines.
Similar situation, only this time it does not appear after an hour or two.
I see the logs sent in the stdout log, but it does not appear in ES.

Answer (score 0):

Things are more confusing than I first anticipated.

For example, this log:

```
Dec  2 10:39:12 foreman dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.50.52 to 6c:ad:f8:26:b1:68 (Chromecast) via eth0
```

The list view under the graph lists the time correctly, but the bargraph has the entry at 23:39:12?

A lag of 13 hours sounds unbelievable, but 13h to the second sounds more like a timezone issue?
Yet all are running with the same date as verified by `date`

Answer (score 0):

Some more information:

```
[root@tool01 tmp]# curl -s XGET http://192.168.50.241:9200/logstash-2014.12.03/_search?pretty=true | tail -n 15; TZ=UTC date
{
  "_index": "logstash-2014.12.03",
  "_type": "syslog",
  "_id": "bOVXPpf9SFOKKPgx7PWfCA",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "message": "Dec  3 00:06:30 foreman dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.50.251 from 00:15:5d:32:14:09 via eth0",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2014-12-03T00:06:30.000Z",
    "type": "syslog",
    "file": "/var/log/messages",
    "host": "foreman.ics.dmz",
    "offset": "3756888",
    "syslog_timestamp": "Dec  3 00:06:30",
    "syslog_hostname": "foreman",
    "syslog_program": "dhcpd",
    "syslog_message": "DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.50.251 from 00:15:5d:32:14:09 via eth0",
    "received_at": "2014-12-02 11:06:31 UTC",
    "received_from": "foreman.ics.dmz",
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_facility": "user-level",
    "syslog_severity": "notice"
  }
},
{
  "_index": "logstash-2014.12.03",
  "_type": "syslog",
  "_id": "5axCp7UgRxmunclFqlgKNw",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "message": "Dec  3 00:06:30 foreman dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.50.251 to 00:15:5d:32:14:09 via eth0",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2014-12-03T00:06:30.000Z",
    "type": "syslog",
    "file": "/var/log/messages",
    "host": "foreman.ics.dmz",
    "offset": "3756982",
    "syslog_timestamp": "Dec  3 00:06:30",
    "syslog_hostname": "foreman",
    "syslog_program": "dhcpd",
    "syslog_message": "DHCPACK on 192.168.50.251 to 00:15:5d:32:14:09 via eth0",
    "received_at": "2014-12-02 11:06:31 UTC",
    "received_from": "foreman.ics.dmz",
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_facility": "user-level",
    "syslog_severity": "notice"
  }
},
{
  "_index": "logstash-2014.12.03",
  "_type": "syslog",
  "_id": "m_MuAZPcS8ixmCn5getvyg",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "message": "Dec  3 00:06:30 spacewalk dhclient[906]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.50.240 port 67 (xid=0x421c37e1)",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2014-12-03T00:06:30.000Z",
    "type": "syslog",
    "file": "/var/log/messages",
    "host": "spacewalk.ics.dmz",
    "offset": "269907",
    "syslog_timestamp": "Dec  3 00:06:30",
    "syslog_hostname": "spacewalk",
    "syslog_program": "dhclient",
    "syslog_pid": "906",
    "syslog_message": "DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.50.240 port 67 (xid=0x421c37e1)",
    "received_at": "2014-12-02 11:06:33 UTC",
    "received_from": "spacewalk.ics.dmz",
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_facility": "user-level",
    "syslog_severity": "notice"
  }
}
Tue Dec  2 19:19:14 UTC 2014
```

So it seems the data is buffered before being written to EL?